# Get results in magento just like BETWEEN keyword in SQL

Tags: php, sql, magento

I've got this problem that I can't solve. Partly because I can't explain it with the right terms. I'm new to this so sorry for this clumsy question.

Below you can see an overview of my goal.

I'm using **Magento CE 1.7.0.2**

In SQL we have a keyword BETWEEN for filter the records between two values.

For Example: `Select * from Mytable where rollnum BETWEEN 10 AND 100;`

Like that I want to use in Magento

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')->addAttributeToSelect('*')->setOrder($choice, 'asc');
```

in the above i want to use that & that should work just like BETWEEN keyword in SQL..

Any Ideas....

Answer (score 0):

```
   $collection->addAttributeToFilter('start_date', array('date' => true, 'to' => $todaysDate))
             ->addAttributeToFilter('end_date', array(
                              array('date' => true, 'from' => $todaysDate),
                              array('null' => true)
                              )
```

Simple way, taking your problem :

```
$_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter(

    array(
        'attribute' => 'rollnum',
        'in' => array(10, 100)
    )
);
```